# How to cherry pick multiple commits using Github Desktop?

Tags: github-desktop

I'm trying to cherry pick the last 10 commits from branch A to B. Github Desktop only lets me cherry pick one commit one at a time? Is it possible to cherry pick 10 commits in one go instead of having to tediously pick them one by one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Github Desktop Sample]
Github Desktop allows you to select multiple commits by shift-dragging commit and right click to cherry-pick all X amount of commits assuming they're in linear order.